# Air bubble on surface of chocolate

Tags: chocolate, ganache

How can I get rid of the air bubbles in the melted chocolate after I have blended with a mixer? I knocked the tray on the table so hard and the air bubble began to surface but it doesn't pop out. Any suggestion to this problem?

I'm making a ganache and have been told to use mixer for a smoother ganache. Other than vibrating the tray, any method I should try? If it's impossible then i will just need to enrobed/powder it instead of making a fudge ganache which were supposed to be served chilled.

Comment: Are you making a ganache as the tags say? Do you have a recipe that actually says to use a mixer?

Comment: Yes, I'm making a ganache and been told to use mixer for smoother ganache . Other than vibrating the tray, any method i should try , if it's impossible then i will just need to enrobed/powder it instead of making a fudge ganache which were supposed to be served chilled.

Comment: I have never heard of making ganache with a mixer. I have, on occasion, heard of *whipping* warmed-up ganache with a very high cream-to-chocolate ratio, but that is with the deliberate intent of *incorporating* air. It's going to be very difficult to *remove* air. Can you post the recipe, or at least the relevant parts of it?

Comment: Are you sure the recipe doesn't call for you to blitz _the chocolate_ in the mixer to make finer chunks that will then melt easier, making a smoother ganache?

Comment: I haven't tried it with chocolate, but for gelatin molds, I find that a fork works well to break the bubbles, or at the very least, corral them all to one side of the container.  (I've also tried wooden skewers, but I find metal is less likely to introduce new bubbles)

Answer (score 3):

It didn’t get rid of ALL the bubbles, but I did find gently pressing my bubbly ganache through a regular sieve (mine is a nylon one) got rid of a lot of them and a further few taps got rid of almost all the rest. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to salvage it, I think about all you can do is heat it until it's well melted and let it settle, stirring gently now and then. Hopefully the air bubbles will eventually all come out. I suspect it won't be perfect, and may take a while.

And in the future, just don't use a mixer. Everything should melt and meld just fine with gentle heat and stirring.

Comment: Once it's warmed up, you might be able to handle it like making a cake and slam the container against the counter a few times to get the bubbles to come to the surface.  (although it might be too viscous for that to work)

Answer (score 1):

There *are* recipes out there that call for a mixer, but they must be executed carefully. 
I used one myself for a ganache-like frosting that needs really a lot of stirring, almost impossible by hand. I tried by hand first, because I didn't trust the blender bit in the recipe, but used it in the end. (Turned out beautifully - and that was for my own wedding cake, so my expectations were super-high.)

Crucial point is, not to get any air bubbles into the ganache; once they are in, it's usually too late. I'd try Cascabel's advice and *gently* heat over a water bath, just to keep it liquid enough that the air rises to the surface naturally - stir occasionally and then perhaps skim the bubbly top layer. You will lose some of the ganache (don't throw it out, it'll still taste fine!), but perhaps the rest will be enough for whatever you need it for.

For your next try, if you can't stir by hand:
The trick to use a mixer - or rather: an immersion blender - is to keep the speed low (if possible with your blender) and the head right at the bottom and somewhat to the side of a high container. Do not use a shallow bowl. Make sure the "vortex" that forms while blending does not reach the head of the blender. Rather stop occasionally. Do not allow that "slurping" sound that happens when the blender sucks in air.

Comment: Thanks, im using the hand blender with the bottom blade. My mistake was  tilting the  blender and allow the surface of choco to flow downwards . What i found out later was that , i should dip it inside and let it do its job under the chocolate and when removing it, i should slowly tilt out the blender side way and not allowing air bubble to get back in.